# Pass devise current_user to a method in a lib file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-oauth, omniauth

I am trying to pass the devise @current_user from my application_controller to a class method in a library file. This is to use the Twitter API. I can get it working by writing the various twitter methods in the application_controller file, but I was wondering how I would do it using a separate lib. file and class instead? The code is as follows:

**lib/twitter_api.rb**

```
class TwitterApi

def self.our_public_tweets
  client.user_timeline('BBCNews', count: 1, exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false)
end

def self.followers
  client.followers.take(5)
end

def self.client
  @client ||= Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
   config.consumer_key        = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_key
   config.consumer_secret     = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_secret
   config.access_token        = current_user.token
   config.access_token_secret = current_user.secret
    end
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

**view file: index.html.erb**

```
  <%= TwitterApi.our_public_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <%= tweet.text %>
  <% end %>

  <%= TwitterApi.followers.each do |follower| %>
    <%= follower.name %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, for a newbie, that isn't clear - can you provide some code to help me out please? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woudl make an instance of the class rather than using class methods.

```
class UserTwitter
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def our_public_tweets
    client.user_timeline('BBCNews', count: 1, exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false)
  end

  def followers
    client.followers.take(5)
  end

  private

  attr_reader :user

  def client
    @client ||= Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_key
      config.consumer_secret = Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_secret
      config.access_token = user.token
      config.access_token_secret = user.secret
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller

```
def index
  @user_twitter = UserTwitter.new(current_user)
end
```

Which then means in your view

```
<% @user_twitter.our_public_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <%= tweet.text %>
<% end %>

<% @user_twitter.followers.each do |follower| %>
  <%= follower.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I cant get that to work im afraid as is comes up with a host of rails errors with undefined methods. Can you clarify whether the 'in your controller' you mean the application controller? When I add this to that and run it, the error is `undefined method "our_public_tweets" for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Whichever controller you're using to display them in the view

Comment: I have an index page on the WelcomeController, so added the following code to the WelcomeController and got an uninitialized constant error on the WelcomeController for user_twitter:

    class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
       @user_twitter = UserTwitter.new(current_user)
      end
    end

Comment: hmm, I restarted the rails server and it seems to work. Why does it take a restart for this to activate? Cheers though, much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure whether things in lib are checked for file changes in development in the same way things in app are